# Looking for a sample Visual Studio 2010 Database Project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know where I can find a thorough VS 2010 Database Project sample.  I have scoured the Internet and am still unable to find any sample VS database projects.

Comment: Do you want a web application (ASP.Net) or a desktop (WinForm or WPF) application?

Comment: A Database project.  There is a type of VS 2010 project called SQL Server 2008 Database Project and that is what I'm looking for specifically.  I'm not looking for a ASP or WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this little walkthrough (MSDN) is what you are looking for:
[Walkthrough: Put an Existing Database Schema Under Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833194.aspx).

These walkthrough is based on the sample database AdventureWorks2008. How to install and configure the sample database is described by another walkthrough. Because of the hyperlink limitation I can't post the link but you will find it by google: "Walkthrough: Installing the AdventureWorks Database".

If you are looking for further information I recommend you the following document from the Microsoft ALM Rangers: [Visual Studio 2010 Database Projects Guidance Document](http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Look through the code samples available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd238515). Not entirely sure what kind of database projects you're looking for, but there is a category for [Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ef4/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4279).

**EDIT:** Also, you might want to check out [this sample chapter](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/0672323435.pdf) that introduces to the basics of database projects, and [this MSDN code sample set](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/dbpromsdbsamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=968).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the same thing.  A database project is not the same as a .NET app that is using the Entity Framework.  What a database project is, is basically using VS to create and manage your DB, schema, views, deployment, etc

Comment: Check the edit. Generally, you are better off looking for official docs (like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx) rather than look for project samples for this specific project type.

Answer (score 0):

in www.codeplex.com there are a lot of examples, on of them is "Expens"

Comment: I can't find a single VS Database Project in code plex and there is nothing under "Expens".  If you are certain it is there, could you provide a link?

Comment: Google agrees with @Someone: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=kwP&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&&sa=X&ei=7_tKTbP1NsXogQeIzYD2Dw&ved=0CBUQvgUoAA&q=Expens+site%3Awww.codeplex.com&nfpr=1